# SharePoint Library Button (JSON formatting) to update current item field value

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, json-formatting, column-formatting, power-automate

I have a formatted Single Line Text field in a SharePoint Library. It is formatted to be a button that executes a Flow. I've created this so I can attach this one flow to multiple libraries. It works well for that purpose, but I need it to perform an additional action: update a different field for the current item.

There are 2 other fields:

- Publishing_Status (choice)
- Last_Published_Date (Date and Time)

Is it possible with a button like below to update the value of another field? Specifically to add a time stamp and select a choice for the choice field?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column- formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
  "action": "executeFlow",
  "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"ffa62926-6bbc-4db1-a409-1aeac8fdde93\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
     "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
 "style": {
   "border": "none",
   "background-color": "transparent",
   "cursor": "pointer"
 },
 "children": [
 {
  "elmType": "span",
  "attributes": {
    "iconName": "Flow"
  },
  "style": {
    "padding-right": "6px"
  }
},
{
   "elmType": "span",
   "txtContent": "Publish"
  }
 ]
}
```

I wanted to use Flow to update the item, but as it may come from one of several libraries, it's not really possible (as far as I can tell).

Thanks.

Comment: You can't update data from JSON view formatting, but I don't see any reason why your Flow couldn't do it.  No matter what item triggers the Flow, you can always use the `Update Item` to update an item in another list, as last long as the connection account your Flow is using has access, it could even be in a different site.  If you don't have the ID of the item you want to update, you can use the `Get Items` action with an OData filter to find it by other metadata criteria.

Comment: Thanks @willman, the only problem is I need to update the metadata of the item. And I can't make that dynamic, right? Like, I have the ID of the document I need to update, I also have the site and the library name - but all those variables will be dynamic. So I can't create the Update File Properties action, because Flow doesn't know what columns are in that list, because it's dynamic.

Comment: I understand where your difficulty lies now, I posted an answer that should let you achieve it through Flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flow designer for the `Update Item` action does limit you to "known" fields, which is frustrating because it is only a UI restriction.  If you were to go through the process of exporting the JSON of your Flow, editing the JSON manually, and re-importing, you could use `Update Item` with entirely dynamic values.  I do not recommended that for this simple operation as that would be a cumbersome process, and there is an easier workaround.

Use the `Send an HTTP Request to SharePoint` to use the [REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints) directly.  You can use it whether you need to [Create](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#create-list-item) a new item in a list or [Update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#update-list-item) and existing one.  Every single part of that action can be a dynamic value, from the SiteURL and API path, to the headers and body. Follow that documentation to format the JSON of your POST body, and for most of your headers, although you can skip the Authorization, Digest, and content-length headers, as Flow will handle those for you.

Comment: Thanks again @willman. This gets me a bit closer. 
I just need to be able to get the ListItemEntityTypeFullName from the list. 
I have managed to run a GET first, to retrieve this, but then I can't seem to use it in my next action. I tried this: {'__metadata': {'type': '@{body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['entity']?['type']}'},'Publishing_Status':'Published'
}
as a shot in the dark, but it didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: try `@{body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['d']?['__metadata']?['type']}`.  Note that if the Flow successfully executed the HTTP Request action, you can always go into that instance of the run history and expand that step to see the exact JSON of it's output, the go back to edit mode to adjust accordingly.

Comment: You are a national treasure.